# Whitelabel Error Page - There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).Spring boot app

Tags: spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am getting

*Whitelabel Error Page*
*This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.*
*Thu Apr 20 01:11:57 IST 2017*
*There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)*.
*No message available**

BookstoreApplication.java

```
package com.bookstore;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BookstoreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BookstoreApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.bookstore.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bookstore</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Bookstore</name>
    <description>frontend part for our bookstore project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <title>Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>

      <body>

        <div class="container">

          <!-- Static navbar -->
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
          </nav>

          <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Test of </h1>
            <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static navbar and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
            <p>
              <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
            </p>
          </div>

        </div> <!-- /container -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

console

```
2017-04-20 01:10:35.000  INFO 8644 --- [           main] com.bookstore.BookstoreApplication       : Starting BookstoreApplication on DESKTOP-12BK4L1 with PID 8644 (started by Avinash Kharche in C:\Users\Avinash Kharche\ECommerce_Spring_Neon\Bookstore)
2017-04-20 01:10:35.005  INFO 8644 --- [           main] com.bookstore.BookstoreApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-20 01:10:35.527  INFO 8644 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@67d48005: startup date [Thu Apr 20 01:10:35 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-20 01:10:37.621  INFO 8644 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-04-20 01:10:37.641  INFO 8644 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-04-20 01:10:37.643  INFO 8644 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.6
2017-04-20 01:10:37.826  INFO 8644 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-04-20 01:10:37.828  INFO 8644 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2308 ms
2017-04-20 01:10:38.119  INFO 8644 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-04-20 01:10:38.124  INFO 8644 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-20 01:10:38.125  INFO 8644 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-20 01:10:38.125  INFO 8644 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-20 01:10:38.125  INFO 8644 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-04-20 01:10:38.554  INFO 8644 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@67d48005: startup date [Thu Apr 20 01:10:35 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-20 01:10:38.672  INFO 8644 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String com.bookstore.controller.HomeController.index()
2017-04-20 01:10:38.679  INFO 8644 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-04-20 01:10:38.679  INFO 8644 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-04-20 01:10:38.748  INFO 8644 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-20 01:10:38.748  INFO 8644 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-20 01:10:38.814  INFO 8644 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-04-20 01:10:39.538  INFO 8644 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-04-20 01:10:39.622  INFO 8644 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-04-20 01:10:39.629  INFO 8644 --- [           main] com.bookstore.BookstoreApplication       : Started BookstoreApplication in 5.211 seconds (JVM running for 5.915)
2017-04-20 01:10:47.623  INFO 8644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-04-20 01:10:47.623  INFO 8644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2017-04-20 01:10:47.647  INFO 8644 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 24 ms
```

No error is showing in console. I once resolve this same issue by deleting .m2 folder and update maven. But this time I have done almost everything(deleting .m2, refereshing, clean, changing workspace) but nothing seems to be working.

Please help i am stuck

Edit:

trace

```
2017-04-20 03:07:28.683 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    :  Disabling the response for futher output
2017-04-20 03:07:28.705 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /favicon.ico
2017-04-20 03:07:28.705 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2017-04-20 03:07:28.705 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    :  Not subject to any constraint
2017-04-20 03:07:28.705 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper   :   Returning non-STM instance
2017-04-20 03:07:28.706 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
2017-04-20 03:07:28.706 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@16acbde3
2017-04-20 03:07:28.706 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@16acbde3
2017-04-20 03:07:28.706 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/favicon.ico]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.706 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler map [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping@4c311da] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2017-04-20 03:07:28.706 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/favicon.ico] are [/**/favicon.ico]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.706 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/favicon.ico] are {}
2017-04-20 03:07:28.707 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/favicon.ico] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], class path resource []], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@bd1111a]]] and 1 interceptor
2017-04-20 03:07:28.707 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter@22ca2b3]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.707 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Testing handler adapter [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter@4ab6bcb5]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.707 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/favicon.ico] is: -1
2017-04-20 03:07:28.707 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Applying "invalid path" checks to path: favicon.ico
2017-04-20 03:07:28.707 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Resolving resource for request path "favicon.ico"
2017-04-20 03:07:28.707 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: ServletContext resource [/]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.707 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: ServletContext resource [/]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.707 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.708 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [META-INF/resources/]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.708 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [resources/]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.708 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [resources/]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.708 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [static/]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.709 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [static/]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.709 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource [public/]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.709 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : No match for location: class path resource [public/]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.709 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Checking location: class path resource []
2017-04-20 03:07:28.709 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.resource.PathResourceResolver    : Found match: class path resource [favicon.ico]
2017-04-20 03:07:28.710 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : No media type found for class path resource [favicon.ico] - not sending a content-type header
2017-04-20 03:07:28.713 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2017-04-20 03:07:28.713 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@16acbde3
2017-04-20 03:07:28.714 DEBUG 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2017-04-20 03:07:28.714 TRACE 3168 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Publishing event in org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@dd8ba08: ServletRequestHandledEvent: url=[/favicon.ico]; client=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]; method=[GET]; servlet=[dispatcherServlet]; session=[null]; user=[null]; time=[8ms]; status=[OK]
```

Comment: Best thing you can do is enable the debug log and see what is going wrong..

Comment: As you are using thymeleaf  you need to put index.html in resources/templates folder. Check if that helps.

Comment: It is already inside templates folder :(

Comment: Hi Vijendra, i have updated trace can you please once check

Comment: From the trace it is clear that template folder is not getting registered. Dispature is only looking in ```/public``` and ```/static```.

Comment: I shifted index.html to static folder ->didn't work
then shifted index.html to public folder ->didn't work
:( :(

Comment: It won't work because you have thymeleaf. You are using ```spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf``` and it looks into ```resources/templates/index.html```

Comment: okay got it.
any resolution? please let me know. I tried to run a different project and that too is not working same issue. Not sure why

Comment: Can you show your folder structure?